# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Hadoop-1.0.1

Tags: java, hadoop

i am working with Hadoop-1.0.1 in Eclipse. I am trying to run [wordcount](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v1.0) application but when i run my WordCount.java, Eclipse shows me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:143)
    at test.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 2 more
```

I have hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar in my `classpath`. Should the application require more jar

Comment: did you have apache-commons logging jar file in classpath?

Comment: nope... i have only hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar in my classpath. Let me add it.

Comment: add the all dependencies lib-jars to classpath..

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy How to add multiple  jars to classpath?

Comment: @Siddhu: Simply right click in the project, go to classpath, browse the location of these jars and select all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are getting this error because either two important logging classes commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar which are related with common logging is either not available from  your classpath or you just don't have it.

In most cases these files are in \lib folder with other Hadoop Jar so when you set class path these jar are accessible. Please verify that you do have these files in your machine and are set in your classpath so they are accessible.

Also when you run "hadoop version" the version comes up as result, the same hadoop-core--SNAPSHOT.jar must be in your $HADOOP_HOME location.

You mentioned that you are running *WordCount.java* instead you should say that you are running WordCount job because you are always using the compiled application as jar not java.

$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/jboss/wordcount.jar org.myhadoop.WordCount /usr/jboss/wordcount/input /usr/jboss/wordcount/output

Comment: I forgot to add apache common logging.jar in my class path. however i am not running the wordcount.jar. i am trying to design my own map reduce and right now i am running source code of [wordcountV2](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v2.0) as a test program to check weather everything is fine or not.

Answer (score 1):

`hadoop-core-1.0.1` is probably not in your classpath: `commons-logging` is actually included several times in the hadoop jar!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not include the common-logging jar file so [Download Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) the jar file depends on version, Then will included it in your program and run it THANK yoU